# Agregar array a ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Saludos estoy intentado generar un grafico de barras con ChartJS, para lo cual tengo la siguiente data obtenida por consola:

```
Array(4) [ 1500, 2500, 2500, 2500 ]
```

asi defino mi ChartJS:

```
   new Chart(
            document.getElementById("chartjs"),
            {"type":"bar","data":{"labels":["Vendedor1","Vendedor2","Vendedor3", 'Vendedor4'],
            "datasets":[
            {"label":"My First Dataset","data":[data],
            "fill":false,
            "backgroundColor":[
                "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
                "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)",
                "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
            ],
            "borderColor":["rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(255, 159, 64)","rgb(255, 205, 86)","rgb(75, 192, 192)"],
            "borderWidth":1
            }]},
            //"options":{"scales":{"yAxes":[{"ticks":{"beginAtZero":true}}]}}
            }
        );
```

lo cual no me arroja ningun dato, dado que es un array y los datos deberias ser de la siguiente forma:

```
data = {1500,2500,2500,2500}
```

agradezco cualquier sugerencia..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que le estás pasando `[data]` en vez de `data` por lo que estarías pasándole un `array` con un único elemento que sería a su vez otro `array`.

```js
let data =[1500, 2000, 2500, 3000];
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx,
            {"type":"bar","data":{"labels":["Vendedor1","Vendedor2","Vendedor3", 'Vendedor4'],
            "datasets":[
            {"label":"My First Dataset","data":data,
            "fill":false,
            "backgroundColor":[
                "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
                "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)",
                "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
            ],
            "borderColor":["rgb(255, 99, 132)","rgb(255, 159, 64)","rgb(255, 205, 86)","rgb(75, 192, 192)"],
            "borderWidth":1
            }]},
            //"options":{"scales":{"yAxes":[{"ticks":{"beginAtZero":true}}]}}
            }
        );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: genial, era tan basico..gracias..!!